# Son of Suckerfish Menu in IE8 closes before links can be selected

Tags: javascript, css, drop-down-menu, suckerfish

So, I've managed to get a "Son of Suckerfish" menu to work in IE8, great. However, there is a problem with the menu in which it doesn't stay "open" long enough for users to click the revealed links. As soon as a user's cursor leaves the link triggering the menu, even if they move below the trigger to select the revealed items, the menu closes back up.

Could someone help me fix my code so that the menu stays open long enough for it to be used, like in Safari, Firefox, et cetera?

Thanks!

Comment: Sure, just gimme ssh access to your machine... or post some code...

Comment: Probably, but we'll need to see some code to be able to help you.

Comment: Thanks to you guys as well. Fortunately JMC's solution was exactly what I needed to do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Generally speaking (in lieu of seeing any of your code), this is caused by the submenu not touching any part of it's `:hover` caller (it's parent element). So you can debug this yourself by outlining the elements in question (either with the IE Developer Bar) or by adding `outline: 1px solid red;` to both elements in your css file. Once you see where the parent element ends and the submenu element begins, you will most likely find that they don't overlap.

Give them a good solid overlap and you will be in business.